# Spring expression language extension in xml files

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to extend and register my own function as detailed here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html see section: 6.5.11 Functions.

However, I wish to use this expression from a spring xml file and not in code as presented in the page.

How do I get a reference to the "StandardEvaluationContext" object used by spring while parsing my xml file? without having that spring can't find my registered function.

Thanks,

Yair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution I found is:

```
public class DBCustomExpressionRegistration implements BeanFactoryAware {

@Override
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    if (beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableBeanFactory) {
        ConfigurableBeanFactory cbf = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
        cbf.setBeanExpressionResolver(new StandardBeanExpressionResolver(){
            @Override
            protected void customizeEvaluationContext(
                    StandardEvaluationContext evalContext) {
                evalContext.addMethodResolver(new InfraReflectiveMethodResolver());
            }
        });
    }

}

public String getDbConfig(String param){
    Configuration configuration  = ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration();             
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Iterator<String> keys = configuration.getKeys();
    while(keys.hasNext()){
        String key = keys.next();
        String value = configuration.getString(key);
        String tempKey = "database.*."+param;
        if (key.matches(tempKey)){
            return value;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("could find pattern for: database.<string>" + param);
}


private class InfraReflectiveMethodResolver extends ReflectiveMethodResolver {

    @Override
    public MethodExecutor resolve(EvaluationContext context, Object targetObject, String name, List<TypeDescriptor> argumentTypes) throws AccessException {

        if ("getDbConfig".equals(name)){
            return new DBMethodExecutor();
        }
        return super.resolve(context, targetObject, name, argumentTypes);
    }

}

private class DBMethodExecutor implements MethodExecutor {

    @Override
    public TypedValue execute(EvaluationContext context, Object target, Object... arguments) throws AccessException {

        try {
            return new TypedValue(getDbConfig((String)arguments[0]), new TypeDescriptor(new MethodParameter(DBCustomExpressionRegistration.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDbConfig",new Class[] { String.class }), -1)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AccessException("Problem invoking method: getDbConfig" , ex);
        }

    }

}
```

}

you use from the spring file like this:

```
<bean id="dbCustomExpressionRegistration" class="com.db.util.DBCustomExpressionRegistration"/>
```

in a bean that needs to use the getDbConfig function:

```
<property name="user" value="#{getDbConfig('username')}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should get you started:

```
public class FunctionRegistrationBean implements BeanFactoryAware{

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        if (beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableBeanFactory) {
            ConfigurableBeanFactory cbf = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
            cbf.setBeanExpressionResolver(new StandardBeanExpressionResolver(){
                @Override
                protected void customizeEvaluationContext(
                        StandardEvaluationContext evalContext) {
                    evalContext.registerFunction("someName", someMethod);
                    evalContext.registerFunction("someOtherName", someOtherMethod);
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Just register this bean in your application context.

Comment: thanks. this is a big help, but apparently I need to add a method resolver as registering the function doesn't work.